# convert Hex UTF-8 bytes to Hex code point

Tags: c#, unicode, utf-8, hex

how can i convert
Hex UTF-8 bytes -E0 A4 A4  to hex code point -  0924

ref: http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=e0+a4+a4&mode=bytes

I need this because when i read Unicode data in c# it is taking it as single byte sequence and displaying 3 characters instead of 1,but i need 3 byte sequence(read 3 bytes and display single character),I tried many solutions but didn't get the result.

If I can display or store a 3-byte sequence utf-8 character then I don't need conversion.

senario is like this:

```
    string str=getivrresult();
```

in str I have a word with each character as 3 byte utf-8 sequence.

Edited:

```
             string str="à¤¤";
             //i want it as "त" in str.

    Character                                   त
    Character name                              DEVANAGARI LETTER TA
    Hex code point                              0924
    Decimal code point                          2340
    Hex UTF-8 bytes                             E0 A4 A4
    Octal UTF-8 bytes                           340 244 244
    UTF-8 bytes as Latin-1 characters bytes     à ¤ ¤
```

Thank You.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: It's really unclear what your input is and what output you want... a sample showing both would be helpful.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I assume the OP wants to reverse `string.Join(" ", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string).Select(x => x.ToString("X2")));`

Comment: @dtb: Possibly, but it's not entirely clear. In particular, it's not obvious whether the input is a byte array or a string...

Comment: BitConverter.ToString(b).Replace("-", "")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `GetString` methdod in the `Encoding` class:

```
byte[] data = { 0xE0, 0xA4, 0xA4 };
string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

The string now contains one character with the character code 0x924.

Comment: Thankyou Guffa I got the answer,its exactly as you told.I am posting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
        //utf-8 Single Byte Sequence input
        string str = "à¤¤";
        int i = 0;
        byte[] data=new byte[3];

        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            string tmpstr = String.Format("{0:x2}", (int)c);
            data[i] = Convert.ToByte(int.Parse(tmpstr, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
            i++;
        }


        //utf-8 3-Byte Sequence Output now stp contains "त".
        string stp = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

Comment: gag ............ how about skipping `string.Format` and `Convert.ToByte` and `int.Parse`, and just saying `data[i] = c;`?